# Android studio gradle error in Java

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am new to android programming (I have some knowledge about programming in Java, though). I downloaded `Android Studio 1.3.2`. I also installed `Java 8` `(jdk1.8.0_60)`. Then I installed Android Studio. I was following the tutorial in developer.android.com. I created a new project. But then the Gradle showed me an error.

```
"Error: Gradle 2.4 requires Java 6 or later to run. Your build is currently configured to use Java 5."
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to post the code that you have so we can know what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
File->Other Settings->Default Project Structure
```

set JDK Location to Java 6 or later there.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the project structure did not work for me. I had to upgrade by Android Studio from 2.0 to 2.2 to get it working. Also, to be safe I did not import settings from my previous version during my initial Studio set-up.